Where to put no_output_timeout for pytest in CircleCI config?
I'm trying to set the no_output_timeout option in my CircleCI config.yml, to allow more time for my tests to run.
I can't work out exactly where this option should go - everywhere I've tried seems to result in the default 10 minutes still being applied.
Here is my current config file.
version: 2.1

orbs:
    aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.4
    sonarcloud: sonarsource/sonarcloud@2.0.0
    python-test: circleci/python@2.1.1

commands:
    configure-role-arn:
        description: "Configure AWS account for ECR and Pod deployment"
        steps:
            - aws-cli/setup:
                  profile-name: redacted
            - aws-cli/role-arn-setup:
                  profile-name: assume_$aws_account_id
                  role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::$aws_account_id:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
                  source-profile: redacted
            - run: >-
                  aws sts assume-role --role-arn
                  "arn:aws:iam::$aws_account_id:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole" --role-session-name
                  AWSCLI-Session

jobs:
    sonar:
        executor:
            name: python-test/default
            tag: "3.10"
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                name: requirements
                command: pip install -r requirements.txt
                  
            - run:
                name: tests
                command: pytest --junitxml=test-report/report.xml
                no_output_timeout: 30m
                
            - run:
                name: coverage
                command: pytest --cov-report term --cov-report xml:coverage-reports/coverage.xml --cov=src/
                no_output_timeout: 20m
                
                
                    
            - sonarcloud/scan

    ci:
        executor: aws-cli/default
        steps:
            - checkout
            - setup_remote_docker:
                  docker_layer_caching: true
                  version: 20.10.12
            - configure-role-arn
            - run:
                  name: "Install tools"
                  command: |
                      sudo wget -O kubectl https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
                      sudo chmod +x ./kubectl
                      sudo cp ./kubectl /bin/kubectl
                  
            - run: ./iac/ci.sh
                  

workflows:
    deploy-development:
        jobs:
            - sonar:
                  requires:
                      - tests
                      - coverage
                  context:
                      - SonarCloud
            - python-test/test:
                  name: tests
                  version: "3.10"
                  pkg-manager: pip
                  test-tool: pytest
                  module-src-dir: "src"
                  context:
                      - NPM
            - python-test/test:
                  name: coverage
                  version: "3.10"
                  pkg-manager: pip
                  test-tool: pytest
                  test-tool-args: "--cov-report term --cov-report xml:coverage-reports/coverage.xml --cov=src/"
                  context:
                      - NPM
            - ci:
                  requires:
                      - tests
                  context:
                      - NPM
                      - AWS
                      - Development
    deploy-production:
        jobs:
            - ci:
                  context:
                      - NPM
                      - AWS
                      - Production
                  filters:
                      branches:
                          only: main


